# When to use composition and when to use inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition

Is there a way of telling when to use composition and when to use inheritance in your code.

Example: Let's say we have 4 classes called `Computer`, `MotherBoard`, `Monitor`, `Keyboard`. I can make `computer` inherit from the other three classes and I can also declare  `MotherBoard`, `Monitor`, `Keyboard` in the field of `computer`, thus for the second case using composition. Which way is better? Which way is preferred by most developers?

Comment: There’s no set rule, it’s a design choice. For your example, inheritance makes no sense; a keyboard is not a computer.

Comment: A computer is composed of (made up from) the other components, so it is hopefully obvious that composition is the appropriate choice here.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have probably given a wrong example, but in general which way is preferred?

Comment: @A.Rizgar does a carpenter prefer screws or joints? Both are valid tools, it depends on the situation.

Comment: This question **might** be closed due to it being overly broad, but your question is quite dependant on the specific situation.  Here is a decent write up of composition vs inheritance.  https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose

Comment: Are you familiar with the *is-a* and *has-a* descriptions?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, i know those terms.

Comment: @hooknc Great article, it answered my question!

Comment: Is a keyboard a computer? No! A computer has a keyboard. There is your answer.

Comment: This is too broad and vague question for SO. Did you google it before asking - you’d find a few million hits and articles.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yes I did google it but I wanted to discuss it with people and get the opinion of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the inheritance in the [following](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose) cases:

- Both classes are in the same logical domain
- The subclass is a proper subtype of the superclass
- The superclass’s implementation is necessary or appropriate for the subclass
- The enhancements made by the subclass are primarily additive.

Otherwise, the composition is appropriate.

Note that in this case, the computer is *composed* of the components you have listed. As a shortcut, I sometimes ask myself the following:

- Does `Computer` *have* a `Mouse`? If so, then use composition. Notice a computer can have no mouse.
- *Is* `MacBook` a `Computer`? If so, then use inheritance.

> ... but in general which way is preferred

In general, the decision should be based on the situation :)